# Extracting/Decoding name from USB Credit Card reader

Tags: usb, decode, credit-card

When I scan a credit card using the USB card reader I get the following output:

`%X1234123412341234^B>NURBz>C>P>XY JDAE^1903000000000000000Zs1234123412341234]1903000000000000000Z`

I should note that I changed the numbers and letters.  When I process this string it is easy to get the credit card number: `1234123412341234` and expiration date: `03/19`

However, in the Name field I see: `B>NURBz>C>P>XY JDAE`

I was expecting to see something like: `CardUser/John`

How do I decode the Name field so that I get the card users name?

Comment: Is the format code (the letter after the first `%`) actually `X` ? Or did you change it from the more-usual `B` ? And what kind of credit card is it?

Comment: Yes it is actually `X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem is that I am not using an English US QWERTY Keyboard layout.  When I changed the keyboard to English US everything works fine. The name now comes out as expected.